# Delete multiple matching patterns from a file

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, grep

Lets say I have a file containing

```
abc aab100 100 cdc 20aaab aaaan
gshgds aab122 ghsgsd cdc aajksj aaasdan
gsgdsg hqusu jsdjsd jksjks jskdk
hjshj aab1jk uiuasu cdc 100ai bbcbxb
arta hyiosa jkulp nnnnnak cdc
```

I want to match two pattern and if both pattern exist, I want to delete that line.

So here my pattern that I want to delete are aab1 and cdc

In the above file, both of these pattern matches in line 1, Line 2 and line 4. So I would like to delete these 3 lines

I can get the results that I want by using grep as

```
grep -v 'aab1.*cdc' test.txt > test1.txt
```

Even I can do this on the same file without writing to a new file by

```
echo "$(grep -v 'aab1.*cdc' test.txt)" > test.txt
```

But Is there any other better/faster/efficient way of doing this without using grep?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Using `grep` for such task is fine, the main issue with your code is the command substitution as it will load the whole output from `grep` into memory. Consider using a temporary file:

```
grep -v 'aab1.*cdc' test.txt > tmp.txt && mv tmp.txt test.txt
```

Alternative you can used sed with `-i` which enables inplace editing (Under the hood sed will use a temporary file as well):

```
sed -i '/aab1.*cdc/d' test.txt
```

There is also [`sponge` from moreutils](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) which will soaks up all it's input before opening the output file:

```
grep -v 'aab1.*cdc' test.txt | sponge test.txt
```

I can't tell you how it's implemented though (Using temporary file or kept in memory)

Answer (score 1):

With sed :

```
sed -i '/aab1.*cdc/d' file
```

The `-i` option is for editing the file *in place*.

Comment: Gave a `^` :-). The op is not clear about whether the patterns should be separate words or not. But, from what I understand from OP's tries, separate words are not a requirement

Comment: Thanks @sjsam. This pattern will also work on `aab1cdc`.

Comment: here it assumes the order is specified too.

Comment: @karakfa The OP says he can get desired output with `grep -v 'aab1.*cdc`. I suppose `aab1` must precede `cdc`.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -n  '/aab1.*cdc/!p' test > test1
```

should also do it

**In short**

We check for the pattern `aab1.*cdc` in each LINE and if it is present we don't print the line. The standard OUT is redirected to a file named `test1`

**Notes**

1. `-n` for suppressing the normal output
2. `/pattern/` is for pattern matching.
3. `p` is for printing lines. So `!p` negates it.This overrides `-n`.

---

**Using perl**

```
perl -ni -e 'print unless (m/aab1/ && m/cdc/)' file
```

**Notes**

1. `-n` for suppressing the normal output
2. `-i` for in-place edit
3. `-e` allows you to define Perl code to be executed by the compiler.
4. `m/aab1/ && m/cdc/` matches(`m`) both(`&&`) the patterns(`/stuff/`).
5. `print unless` takes care that a line is printed if both patters are not present.

   ---

**Another `sed` solution** based on [[ @tripleee's ]](https://stackoverflow.com/users/874188/tripleee) answer

```
sed -n  '/aab1/!{/cdc/!p}' test > test1
```

**Notes**

This implements the branching as mentioned in this `awk` [[ solution ]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38106537/1620779).

Comment: Is `perl` faster than `sed` in this case?

Comment: @mona_sax With the small data, I believe `sed` is as fast as `perl` in this case, can't confirm though. The op may be able to confirm this.

Answer (score 1):

if the order of the patterns is specified

```
$ awk '!/aab1.*cdc/' file
```

if any order is possible

```
$ awk '!(/aab1/ && /cdc/)' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Awk to the rescue.

```
awk '!/aab1/ || !/cdc/' file
```

If `aab1` is not matched or `cdc` is not matched, (perform the default action, which is to) print the line.

This extends nicely to scenarios where you don't care about the order of the matches, which gets complex quickly if you are constrained to a single regex.

The same in `sed`:

```
sed -e '/aab1/!b' -e '/cdc/d' file
```

Generalizing to more than two patterns, if there is a mismatch on a pattern, skip the rest of this script for this line. If we reach the final regex, we matched all the patterns, so we delete this line. (Otherwise, we print.)